Why didn't Harry go back to Grimmauld Place in the Easter holidays in OotP?
Harry is desperate to talk to Sirius after being in Snape's memory. He can't write to him because Umbridge is checking the post, and can't use Floo powder because the fires are monitored. However, when it's the Easter holidays, rather than going back to Grimmauld Place or the Burrow and getting a chance to see him he stays at school.
Is there a reason given for why he doesn't go 'home' for the holidays? I know he's revising for his OWLs (ditto Ron and Hermione), but Ginny and the twins are also there, because they help with the plan to see Sirius, but they're not in exam years.
Was there an Order- or Educational Decree-based reason none of them went home?

Students in their 5th and 7th year apparently are not allowed home during the Easter break. They are excused lessons, but expected to use the time to revise for their OWLS and NEWTS.

The weather grew breezier, brighter and warmer as the Easter holidays passed, but Harry, along with the rest of the fifth- and seventh- years, was trapped inside, revising, traipsing back and forth to the library


Hi! Your answer might be correct, but the quoted paragraph doesn't really seem to support it. It's just saying Harry and the other students who are about to have their exams have the discipline to go to the library instead of going outside enjoy the sunny weather.

"trapped" to me indicates more than just self-discipline.

Is there any evidence in the books that any student goes home for Easter at any point? It has been a few years since I read them, but it is not something I remember ever being mentioned.

I don't have my copies to hand (that's why I'm asking here) but I'm sure in at least one, maybe the first, it says Harry signs up to stay — which implies most go?

@Justinw In Deathly Hallows Narcissa pointedly mentions that Draco is home for the Easter holiday when the Trio is captured, and Ginny going home for that same holiday and never coming back is what left Neville alone leading the new DA. After Harry blows up Marge, Fudge mentions the Dursleys are willing to accept him back as long as he stays during both the Easter & Christmas holidays, which implies staying is optional.

Draco is in 7th year then, so presumably are allowed to go home.

@BeginTheBeguine Although if Draco  could go home as a 7th Year, then this answer would not be correct, unless the DH era Hogwarts changed the rule/gave an exception? Or the Umbridge lead Hogwarts restricted it specifically for that year. Neither of which are (probably) backed up by any book-evidence. Although personally I read the quoted passage in the answer as them being metaphorically trapped because they had a pressing need to revise as their OWL/NEWT exams started pretty soon after, and so could not spend time relaxing outside in the nicer weather as the other students did?

It's surprising to me that not only Wizards, but specifically the Malfoys, observe the resurrection of Christ as a holiday.

@Turbo According to the author, Hogwarts is a multifaith school, and 1 Corinthians 15:26 and Matthew 6:21 “almost epitomize the series”. By the last book, it's clear she wants Harry's plotline to mimic Jesus's (though personally, I think Aslan did it better). British society isn't secular: the Easter date algorithm is enshrined in law. Even if the Malfoys are secular, them observing Easter is one of the less implausible aspects of the Harry Potter setting.

@Justinw See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186309/how-many-times-a-year-does-the-hogwarts-express-run/202344#202344

@Alex I am not seeing what that adds that was not already covered by Martheen's comment above. Both of which contradict this answer that 5th/7th years are not allowed to go home at Easter, in DH Malfoy is a 7th year and did in fact go home.
